# Issue handling CSV values in query string using Swagger generated client and server classes

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger, jersey-2.0

In one of my APIs Swagger specification I've created a CSV array parameter like this:

```
...
- name: formats
          in: query
          description: The format(s) in which the generated report should be returned.
          type: array
          collectionFormat: csv
          items:
            type: string
            enum:
              - pdf
              - png
...
```

Then via 'swagger-codegen' I generated the server classes with -l 'jaxrs', and the client classes with -l 'java'.

The problem I'm having is that my client classes are creating the HTTP request like this:

http://.....:.../.../?...&formats=value1,value2&...

And when the request is handled by my server classes I'm getting an array with a single String with value 'value1,value2'

If my client classes created the HTTP request like this:

http://.....:.../.../?...&formats=value1&formats=value2&....

Then my server classes would correctly instance an array with a 2 values 'value1' and 'value2'

In my generated client classes the function that is generating the query string value is like this:

```
/**
     * Format to {@code Pair} objects.
     *
     * @param collectionFormat collection format (e.g. csv, tsv)
     * @param name Name
     * @param value Value
     * @return A list of Pair objects
     */
    public List<Pair> parameterToPairs(String collectionFormat, String name, Object value){
        List<Pair> params = new ArrayList<Pair>();

        // preconditions
        if (name == null || name.isEmpty() || value == null) return params;

        Collection valueCollection = null;
        if (value instanceof Collection) {
            valueCollection = (Collection) value;
        } else {
            params.add(new Pair(name, parameterToString(value)));
            return params;
        }

        if (valueCollection.isEmpty()){
            return params;
        }

        // get the collection format
        collectionFormat = (collectionFormat == null || collectionFormat.isEmpty() ? "csv" : collectionFormat); // default: csv

        // create the params based on the collection format
        if (collectionFormat.equals("multi")) {
            for (Object item : valueCollection) {
                params.add(new Pair(name, parameterToString(item)));
            }

            return params;
        }

        String delimiter = ",";

        if (collectionFormat.equals("csv")) {
            delimiter = ",";
        } else if (collectionFormat.equals("ssv")) {
            delimiter = " ";
        } else if (collectionFormat.equals("tsv")) {
            delimiter = "\t";
        } else if (collectionFormat.equals("pipes")) {
            delimiter = "|";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
        for (Object item : valueCollection) {
            sb.append(delimiter);
            sb.append(parameterToString(item));
        }

        params.add(new Pair(name, sb.substring(1)));

        return params;
    }
```

Maybe the problem isn't in the generated classes but either in:

- In my web server's configuration. I'm using 'Wildfly 10.x'
- In my Jersey configuration in 'web.xml'

Any ideas?

Comment: `formats=value1,value2` is the correct representation of `collectionFormat: csv`. `formats=value1&formats=value2` corresponds to `collectionFormat: multi`. So the problem is likely on the server side.

Comment: Yes I also believe that the problem is in the server side. The problem is that until now I was unable to determine if the problem is from Wildfly, Jersey or the generated server classes!... What's you suspicion?

Comment: It seems to be a codegen issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/2961

Comment: Thanks Hellen! I was hopping this problem was due to missing configuration, but the 'swagger-codegen' issue you pointed out describes exactly the problem I'm having. Kind of worried it's still open for more than one year... Guess a lot of people are using the same workaround  as me... Either that or JAX-RS as died and no one told me...